# Write SQL & Hive query to print the year in which the 2nd highest salary was paid for each country?

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql, greatest-n-per-group

Write SQL and HIVE query to print the year in which the 2nd highest salary was paid for each country?.

Please provide query for the below table

```
country,salary,year
india,1000,2017
japan,2000,2017
germany,1500,2017
india,1250,2018
japan,500,2018
china,955,2017
japan,850,2019
china,1150,2018
india,1250,2019
```

Comment: What is the problem with current query ? What you get ? Where is your query ?

Comment: Hi @VENKY, you can be helped by the following tutorial to have your problem solved: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

something like:

```
select 
    t.*
from (
    select
        tbl.*,
        row_number() over(partition by country order by salary desc) rn
    from 
        tbl
) t
where 
    t.rn = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

The big question is how you handle ties.  Presumably, you mean the second highest *distinct* salary.  In that case, you are specifically looking for the `dense_rank()` window function:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             dense_rank() over (partition by country order by salary desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where t.seqnum = 2;
```

Now, the challenge with this is that it could return more than one row in the event of ties.  If you specifically want one row, then:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             dense_rank() over (partition by country order by salary desc) as ranking,
             row_number() over (partition by country, salary order by country) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where t.ranking = 2 and seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you all. I want below output.Gordon Linoff's 2nd query giving exact result but germany column is missing. Can you please provide the query.
country salary year
japan 850 2019
china 955 2017
india 1000 2017
germany 1500 2017

Comment: @VENKY . . . Germany is missing because there is only one row -- hence, there is no year with a second highest salary.  Hence, "Germany" in the result set would not answer your question.